# Crystal lang : concat path in a cross-platform way?

Tags: crystal-lang

Unix uses `/` to separate folders but Windows uses `\`, so I wonder a safe way for cross-platform to concat two paths like `/tmp/` + `temp_file.xxx`.

Comment: There isn't class like `Path` as far as I know in `api 0.26.1`

Comment: FWIW, Windows accepts '/' as a path separator in the file-system level API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just after a minute, I found the answer, [`File.join`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.26.1/File.html#join%28%2Aparts%29%3AString-class-method) (-_-)